# How can I add a key and its value to a dictionary?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following variable:

```
var params = [
    "long": lon,
    "lat": lat,
    "radius": radius,
    "deleted": "false"
]
```

and I would like to add a new pair to it:

```
"username": "blablah"
```

How can I do it?

I tried with:

```
params.setValue("blablah", forKey: "username")
```

but it threw error:

```
...this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key username.'
```

Comment: create a mutable copy of params, then add to that.  as it is, the original is immutable.

Comment: hmm can you show me any example of that? I'm not exactly sure how to do that...

Comment: `var mutableParams = params`

Comment: (Sure the error is relating to that line?)

Comment: Yes, it breaks there... I did what @danh suggested but it didn't help, still the same error :(

Comment: you mean you tried setValue on the mutable copy?'

Comment: yes, precisely, I'm still getting an error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSDictionaryI 0x7ae09850> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key username.'`

Comment: You declared your `params` as `var`, so it's mutable. No need to crate a mutable copy. Just write `params["blablah"] = "username"`.

Comment: @OOPer I tried that, but the compiler throws error `cannot assign through subscript: subscript is get-only`

Comment: Have you declared your `params` exactly as the code you have shown?

Comment: @OOPer yes I did, check it out http://i.imgur.com/arVDSTz.png I have no idea what might be wrong here :(

Comment: Guys, I found a problem and a solution... I added `as [String: AnyObject]` at the end of declaration of params and now it works....

Comment: Please clarify in what version of Xcode are you trying?

Comment: Xcode 7.3 (7D175)

Comment: Thanks for clarification. The same behaviour (which I did not know till seeing this post) is also found in Xcode 7.3.1 (7D1014). It seems Swift 2.2 infers the Dictionary literal's type as `NSDictionary` when having different unrelated types, so, it's got immutable. Swift 3 reports error for such "heterogenous collection literal", and suggests adding `as` annotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two issues. First, there is not enough information for the compiler to determine the dictionary type, so it should be specified. Also, use subscript notation to set the new value. See below:

```
var params: [String : Any] = [
    "long": lon,
    "lat": lat,
    "radius": radius,
    "deleted": "false"
]

params["username"] = "blablah"
```